# Export List of Lists as CSV into seperate Files or Excel Sheets

Tags: r, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

I have a list of lists `mylists` with `data.table` objects

```
x <- rep("example",5)
y <- 1:5
list1 <- list('a'= data.table(x,y),'b' = data.table(x,y))
list2 <- list('c'= data.table(x,y), 'd' = data.table(x,y))
mylists <- list('Output1'= list1,'Output2' =list2)
mylists
```

I want to export every object of every list as a **separate CSV File** (preferably using `fwrite` from `data.table`) named like the object i.e. `Output1_a.csv`

I **cannot** `rbind` to one data.frame/table as the data needs to be kept separate.

I've tried using
`lapply(mylists,fwrite)`
but have trouble producing separate files with different names.

**Additionally** how could I produce an `xlsx File` where all objects of `mylists` are stored into separate sheets named as described above.

I'd like to know both ways as this might be useful for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the xlsx version you could do something like this

```
x <- rep("example",5)
y <- 1:5
list1 <- list('a'= data.table(x,y),'b' = data.table(x,y))
list2 <- list('c'= data.table(x,y), 'd' = data.table(x,y))
mylists <- list('Output1'= list1,'Output2' =list2)
purrr::walk(names(mylists), 
            function(x){
               writexl::write_xlsx(mylists[[x]], 
                                   path = paste0(x, ".xlsx"))
            })
```

this will produce xlsx files with the names of the outer list and sheets with the name of the inner lists

for the csv would I do something like this to first flatten the list

```
mylists_flat <- unlist(mylists, recursive = FALSE)
walk(names(mylists_flat), 
     function(x){
       write.csv(mylists_flat[[x]], 
                 file = paste0(x, ".csv"))
     })
```

this should produce csv files with the name `<outerlist_name>.<innerlist_name>.csv`

Comment: Thank you. Both work like a charm. However, the `XLSX approach` gives me file for every `outerlist`. I guess my explanation was not entirely precise here. How can I aggregate all `outerlist.innerlist` to ONE SINGLE XLSX file ?

Comment: you could just use the flat list in the write_xlsx function that should do it
`writexl::write_xlsx(mylist_flat, "combined.xlsx")`

Comment: Right. I did not think of that. Thank you for your time!